# How can I avoid ReentrantLock when I query with multi-threads in Neo4j

Tags: multithreading, caching, locking, neo4j

I create a graph consisted of 1 million nodes and 100 million relationships. I have only 16 GB RAM, which can not cache all the node and relationship objects. I choose gcr cache_type and warm up the graph by traversing the nodes and relationships.
My machine has 16-core CPU. The problem is that the performance of one query by single thread is good(30 ms). but the performance of multi-threads drops a lot, e.g., the average cost for one query is about 100 ms with 4-threads. I find out that NodeManager.lockId() takes up most time. The source of NodeManager is here:

http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.neo4j/neo4j-kernel/1.9.2/org/neo4j/kernel/impl/core/NodeManager.java?av=f

It seems when we get a node or relationship, it will try to do something to cache them, which generates a ReentrantLock and block the threads.

I don't know how to avoid the lock or do something else to reduce the overhead. I want to improve the performance of multi-threads. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for reference I'd like to note that the locking you're refering to will not exist in 2.0, where 2.0-M06 will be the first milestone featuring this.

Comment: I've read https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/pull/1202 about your commit and tried 2.0.0-M05, but "neo4j.kernel.impl.cache.LockstripedCache.lockId" still takes up most time. I've tried to add 2.0.0-M06 to my pom file, but maven fails to compile. Must I use 2.0-M06?  Below is part of my pom file
            <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>neo4j-enterprise</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0-M05</version>